# Default value of minimum_should_match?

Tags: elasticsearch

Cant find which is the default value of `minimum_should_match` in the docs

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html

Is it `0` or `1`, or depends if the query has just `should` or `filter` context?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The default value of `minimum_should_match` depends on the query and on the context:

- `1`: in [query context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/query-filter-context.html) and `should` is alone (no `must` or `filter`)
- `1`: in [filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/query-filter-context.html) (e.g. inside a `filter` part of a `bool` query; true until ES 6.7)
- `0`: in [filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/query-filter-context.html) (e.g. inside a `filter` part of a `bool` query; true since ES 7.0, see notes below)
- `0`: in [query context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/query-filter-context.html) and there are `must` and `should` (or `filter` and `should`)

Can be found in the documentation of the [`bool`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query:

> If the bool query is in a query context and has a must or filter
>   clause then a document will match the bool query even if none of the
>   should queries match. In this case these clauses are only used to
>   influence the score. If the bool query is a filter context or has
>   neither must or filter then at least one of the should queries must
>   match a document for it to match the bool query. This behavior may be
>   explicitly controlled by settings the minimum_should_match parameter.

#### A few examples

query context and `should` is alone:

```
POST _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "should" : [
        { "term" : { "tag" : "wow" } },
        { "term" : { "tag" : "elasticsearch" } }
      ]
      # default:
      # "minimum_should_match" : 1
    }
  }
}
```

query context and `must` together with `should`:

```
POST _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
      },
      "should" : [
        { "term" : { "tag" : "wow" } },
        { "term" : { "tag" : "elasticsearch" } }
      ]
      # default:
      # "minimum_should_match" : 0
    }
  }
}
```

filter context:

```
POST _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
          },
          "should": [
            { "term" : { "tag" : "wow" } },
            { "term" : { "tag" : "elasticsearch" } }
          ]
          # default (until ES 6.7):
          # "minimum_should_match" : 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Update: ES 7.0 related changes

In Elasticsearch 7.0 [the filter context has been removed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-7.0.html#_the_filter_context_has_been_removed), which means effectively that in filter context its default value now is `0`.

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55797064/5095957) which helped me to discover this.

Comment: Hi Nikolay, thanks for your answer! Would you have any clue as to how the score would be calculated in a bool query with must and should clauses? I mean the score for ranking the result as per https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/practical-scoring-function.html

Comment: @s1d No, unfortunately I don't have such knowledge, I would also be curious to learn this. I do believe that the should be no difference in scoring between `should` and `must`, the latter filter only those results that match its query in any way, and should does not filter (only increases the score for those also matching the `should`).

Comment: Thank you for posting this, saved me a lot of time.