# Elasticsearch - This search doesn't return the correct results after upgrading from 6.7 to 7.0

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{  
  "query":{  
    "constant_score":{  
      "filter":{  
        "bool":{  
          "should":{  
            "terms":{  
              "field_a":[  
                "value1", "value2"
              ]
            }
          },
          "must":{  
            "term":{  
              "field_b":"value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This search was supposed to return the results containing value1 or value2 in field_a and value in field_b.

So similar to this MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field_a IN ('value1', 'value2') AND field_b = value
```

After the upgrade it will return all the results where field_b = value. The first part of the query is completely ignored.
Any suggestions for a fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running into [this breaking change](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/breaking-changes-7.0.html#_the_filter_context_has_been_removed). `minimum_should_match` is no longer being set to `1`. To correct this, explicitly set your `minimum_should_match` to `1`

Your new query could be fixed like this:

```
{  
  "query":{  
    "constant_score":{  
      "filter":{  
        "bool":{  
          "should":{  
            "terms":{  
              "field_a":[  
                "value1", "value2"
              ]
            }
          },
          "minimum_should_match": 1,
          "must":{  
            "term":{  
              "field_b":"value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```