# ElasticSearch set minimum_should_match parameter default globally

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a pre-existing ES 7.x queries which use both `should` and `filter/must` clauses together like so for example

```
"query": {
"bool": {
  "should": [
     ....
   ] 
  "must": [
    ....
  ]
}
```

},

And these queries return data because because by default `minimum_should_match` param is set to 1. However, I know since Elastic 7x there's a breaking change and when `should` clause is used in conjunction with either `must`/`filter` then `minimum_should_match` parameter is set to 0 so `should` clause doesn't get applied by default (see [see this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55795434/elasticsearch-this-search-doesnt-return-the-correct-results-after-upgrading-f/55797064#55797064) and [elastic doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/query-dsl-bool-query.html#bool-min-should-match)). That's a massive breaking change!! It will be a huge change for me to add `minimum_should_match` = 1 in every query I use `should` so I wonder whether there's some global setting I could use to default my ElasticSearch's the parameter `minimum_should_match` = 1 whenever `should` is used?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible to set the value of `minimum_should_match` globally. How do you build your queries? respectively do you store them somewhere?

Comment: some queries are static but most are dynamically build

Comment: Then even better, whenever you add a `should` clause in your application logic, you can just add `minimum_should_match` as well, easy peasy.

Comment: good suggestion but it will require code changes so I was hoping I could run some query against my ES cluster to default minimum_should_match  to 1 regardless. this looks like a massive breaking change!

Comment: Well, there will always be breaking changes. That's why major releases are for. Since 7.0 came out more than 2 years ago (April 2019), that's plenty of time to prepare for this migration, don't you think?

Comment: well, interestingly enough, I noticed the behaviour changed from ES 7.5+ onwards instead of 7.0. Currently, I've got 7.4x and it works fine and I noticed the difference when I attempted to upgrade to 7.10x. Any ideas why that might be the case?

Comment: For reference, [here is the PR](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/35354) that explains it all.

Comment: I understand it's weird but I noticed the following - the combination bool{'should' + 'filter'} has been working fine till 7.4 but since 7.5 it stopped working fine. bool{'should' + 'must'} stopped working since 7.x though