# Elasticsearch Bool query with minimum_should_match set to zero not honored

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk, booleanquery

I add 3 documents

```
POST test/_doc
{"value": 1}

POST test/_doc
{"value": 2}

POST test/_doc
{"value": 3}
```

then do the following query I **expect** to return all the 3 docs with documents matching **should** clause being ranked higher

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 0,
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "value": {
              "gte": 2
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but instead i get only 2 docs (value 2,3)  `"minimum_should_match": 0,` does not have any effect until i add the `filter` or `must` clause in the bool query like below,

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
       "filter": [ { "match_all": { } } ],
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "value": {
              "gte": 2
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**What I want**

in the bool query, either the **must** clause or **filter** clause is empty or filled, the **should** clause **must** not filter any documents BUT only participate in ranking, please share how can i achieve that, thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48984706/default-value-of-minimum-should-match

Answer (score 1):

It's a little weird that `minimum_should_match: 0` is not working with the `should` clause. This may be due to the documentation mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html)

> No matter what number the calculation arrives at, a value greater than
> the number of optional clauses, or a value less than 1 will never be
> used. (ie: no matter how low or how high the result of the calculation
> result is, the minimum number of required matches will never be lower
> than 1 or greater than the number of clauses.

There are two ways in which you can get all the documents in the result and using the `should` clause only for the ranking purpose

1. Use `must` or `filter` clause with `match_all` query, which you already figured out as shown in the question above.
2. Another way could be to use the `should` clause with the `boost` parameter

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "value": {
              "gte": 2,
              "boost": 2.0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "value": {
              "lt": 2,
              "boost": 1.0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "68040640",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 2.0,
        "_source": {
          "value": 2
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "68040640",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 2.0,
        "_source": {
          "value": 3
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "68040640",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "value": 1
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Kamboh did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :-)