# Terms Set Query's minimum_should_match_field does not behave as expected when the provided field has value zero

Tags: elasticsearch

I am wondering, using "terms set" query, why when a field that specified by the **minimum_should_match_field** has value "0", it behaves as if it has value "1".

To replicate the problem, I take the example from the [Elasticsearch doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-set-query.html) and construct three steps below.

Step 1:

**Create a new index**

```
PUT /job-candidates
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "programming_languages": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "required_matches": {
        "type": "long"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Step 2:

**Create two docs with required_matches set to zero**

```
PUT /job-candidates/_doc/1?refresh
{
  "name": "Jane",
  "programming_languages": [ "c++", "java" ],
  "required_matches": 0
}
```

and also

```
PUT /job-candidates/_doc/1?refresh
{
  "name": "Ben",
  "programming_languages": [ "python" ],
  "required_matches": 0
}
```

Step 3:

**Search for docs with the following search**

```
GET /job-candidates/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms_set": {
      "programming_languages": {
        "terms": [ "c++", "java"],
        "minimum_should_match_field": "required_matches"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Expected Results**: I expect step 3 returns both docs "Jane" and "Ben"

**Actual Results**: but it only returns doc "Jane"

I don't understand. If **minimum_should_match** is 0, doesn't it mean that an returned doc do not need to match any term(s), therefore "Ben" doc should also be returned?

Some links I found but still can't answer my question:

1. [minimum_should_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html)

- It looks like **minimum_should_match** can't not be zero, but it does not says how search works if it's indeed zero or more than the number of optional values.

2. A discussion of [default value for minimum_should_match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48984706/default-value-of-minimum-should-match)

- But they didn't discuss the "terms set" query in particular.

Any clarification will be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When looking at the [`terms_set` source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/TermsSetQueryBuilder.java#L242), we can see that the underlying Lucene query being used is called `CoveringQuery`.

So the explanation can be found in Lucene's source code of `CoveringQuery`, whose [documentation](https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/main/lucene/sandbox/src/java/org/apache/lucene/sandbox/search/CoveringQuery.java#L62-L65) says

> Per-document long value that records how many queries should match. Values that are less than 1 are treated like `1`: only documents that have at least one matching clause will be considered matches. Documents that do not have a value for `minimumNumberMatch` do not match.

And a little further, [the code](https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/main/lucene/sandbox/src/java/org/apache/lucene/sandbox/search/CoveringQuery.java#L175) that sets `minimumNumberMatch` is pretty self-explanatory:

```
final long minimumNumberMatch = Math.max(1, minMatchValues.longValue());
```

We can simply sum it up by stating that it doesn't really make sense to send a `terms_set` query with `minimum_should_match: 0` as it would be equivalent to a `match_all` query.